# kivy - strange hitbox for scatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

Let's take a look at a simple tutorial app ...

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class Main(App):

    def build(self):

        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text="Error?",
                      font_size=150
                      )

        s.add_widget(l)
        f.add_widget(s)
        return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Supposedly, this adds a label to the app that can be moved, resized, rotated ...
I *can* move, resize and rotate it, but the hitbox seems shifted.

I.e. I can click WAY above the label or left of the label, but the left size of the label is unresponsive:[image]

This doesn't look like intended behaviour.

Where'd I go wrong? / How do I fix this?

Running under Python 3.6 on Windows 10, btw.

Console output:

```
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\user1291\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-06-02_48.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.4.0 - Build 21.20.16.4590'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 4
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.40 - Build 21.20.16.4590'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <b"WARNING: 0:7: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <b"WARNING: 0:7: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Answer (score 1):

This *is* the correct behavior, it is just not explicit. By default, a widget assumes the size of its parent. So your FloatLayout is the size of the App (the whole screen), your Scatter is the size of your FloatLayout, and your Label is the size of the Scatter. So, the size of the Label is the same as the size of the App.

For "intended behavior", you have to set the size of your label by giving it a `size_hint=(None, None)` (the layout sets the size automatically for you using `size_hint` by default) and then you can manually set the site with `size=(x, y)`.

Here's a little code to play around with:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string("""
FloatLayout:
    Scatter:
        id: s       
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        Label:
            id: l
            text: "Error?"
            font_size: 150
""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Note how I added a canvas that is red to indicate how big the Scatter is. Now you can change the Scatter's size and see what happens. You can add the same `canvas.before: ...` to the Label but change its color. Then you will begin to see the logical reasoning and why it seemed so weird.

I really recommend you figure out what's going on, meanwhile, here's the full solution for this exact problem, in case you really get stuck:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string("""
FloatLayout:
    Scatter:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: l.texture_size

        Label:
            id: l
            text: "Error?"
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 150
""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything - or at least not the way I try it. Can you make an example?

Comment: I edited my answer to include some code you can play around with and debug. Other than that, you can read about the Scatter and layouts in the official docs. Hope that helps.